# Localhost and NextJs custom middleware

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a question about the nextjs page middleware, [see here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware), according to the documentation the request object should contain geo, IP, ua, cookies and nexturl properties.

So all I am trying to do is get the users location through page middleware like this:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function middleware(req) {
  const { nextUrl, geo } = req;
  console.log(geo) //=> always empty {}
  const country = geo.country || 'US'
  nextUrl.searchParams.set('locale', country);


  return NextResponse.rewrite(nextUrl);
}
```

But when I run my project locally the geolocation is an empty object, why?

Will all hosting providers send geolocation data, or does it depend on the provider?

Answer (score 1):

Geo location will always be empty when running in your local environment, and it does depend on the provider

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/39619